# C# if counter how to change button "function" after pressing it

Tags: c#, if-statement, xamarin

Easy question for C# novice

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace Sukkis
{
    [Activity(Label = "sukkis", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        string person = "sukkis";
        string age = "24";
        string place = "hell";
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
            TextView kentta = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tiedot);

            if (count == 2)
            {
                button.Click += delegate { kentta.Text = "Info"; };
                button.Click += delegate { button.Text = "Click additional info"; };
                count--;
            }
            else
            {
                button.Click += delegate { kentta.Text = $"Name: {person}\nage: {age}\nPlace: {place} \n \nC# is fun"; };
                button.Click += delegate { button.Text = "Hide"; };
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to fix this function? Now that works when I press button first time but it wont run function again after second press. How to implement that if loop properly to change text after every other pressing button? Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `if` statement should be placed inside click handler

```
button.Click += delegate {
  if (count == 2)
  {
    kentta.Text = "Info";
    button.Text = "Click additional info";
    count--;
  } else{
     kentta.Text = $"Name: {person}\nage: {age}\nPlace: {place} \n \nC# is fun"; };
     button.Text = "Hide";
     count++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

is better if u use absolute numbers instead ++ & --
Try with this:

```
if (count == 2)
{
     button.Click += delegate { kentta.Text = "Info"; };
     button.Click += delegate { button.Text = "Click additional info"; };
     count = 1;
}
else if(count == 1)
{
     button.Click += delegate { kentta.Text = $"Name: {person}\nage: {age}\nPlace: {place} \n \nC# is fun"; };
     button.Click += delegate { button.Text = "Hide"; };
     count = 2;
}
```

Comment: In this case, it's better to just use a boolean